# How does Rust know which trait methods are required or provided?

Tags: rust

From the [`std::iter::Iterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next) documentation, I can see that only the `next` method is required:

> Required Methods
>
> ```
> fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>
> ```

But from the [source code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/iterator.rs.html#31-2165), after removing comments:

```
pub trait Iterator {
    /// The type of the elements being iterated over.
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    type Item;
    ......
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>;
    ......
    #[inline]
    #[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
    fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) { (0, None) }
    ......
}
```

I can see, except for the `#[inline]` attribute, there is no difference between required and provided methods. How does Rust know which method is required or provided?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is rather simple: the provided (optional) functions have a default implementation, not the required.

Note that you can re-implement the provided functions if you wish so it can perform better than the default one for your particular struct/enum.

Answer (score 9):

> except for the `#[inline]` attribute, there is no difference between required and provided methods

There is a huge difference, you just are ignoring the (lack of) formatting. Allow me to reformat for you:

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>;

fn size_hint(&self) -> (usize, Option<usize>) { // Starting with `{`
    (0, None)                                   //
}                                               // Ending with `}`
```

All the default methods *have a function body*. The required methods do not.

I'd highly recommend rereading [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition), specifically [the chapter about traits and default implementations](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch10-02-traits.html#default-implementations). This resource is a much better way to get started with introductory topics like this than reading arbitrary snippets of the standard library.