# How do I write a trait method that knows the implementor is [u8]?

Tags: rust

I'm implementing a trait for `&[u8]` but I cannot use `self` in the trait implementation. I assume that the trait can not detect the type and I should use a `where` clause, but I don't know how can I use it without an implementor.

```
use std::fmt::Debug;

pub trait Xor: Debug {
    fn xor(&self, key_bytes: &[u8]) -> &[u8] {
        for n in &self[..] {
            dbg!(n);
        }
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

impl Xor for [u8] {}

fn main() {
    let xa = b"1234";
    xa.xor(b"123");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ece590b3cd3ed65f3a840d013ce8a00e)

```
error[E0608]: cannot index into a value of type `&Self`
 --> src/main.rs:5:19
  |
5 |         for n in &self[..] {
  |                   ^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: That said, I suspect this is an XY problem in that you're trying to write a [provided method of the trait](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6e6626073599ceab8c80a0145c1f40d5) when really you just want to implement it [for `[u8]` alone](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=173a4b274942e7684184f5d306ab6dda).

Comment: @trentcl: is it possible to implement the trait for several kind of types without implementor ?
check the following playground : https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3f7ba1000bb371d5380fd249cebd2283

Comment: Sure, if they have some commonality, like implementing a common trait. `String` and `&[u8]` both implement `AsRef<[u8]>`, so you can use that to get an indexable byte slice: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bfd417e8659dd6bb46160c210d3ad448)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two places you can write the body of a trait method:

- inside the trait itself, as a *provided method*
- inside an `impl` block.

If a method is not provided, it is *required*, which means all implementors have to write their own body in the appropriate `impl` block.

Provided methods can only use properties that are common to *all* the implementors of the trait, which means you can only use other trait methods or methods of supertraits (like `: Debug`). But methods in an `impl` block may use properties that are specific to the type implementing the trait. You want to use something specific to `[u8]` -- indexing via `[..]` -- so `xor` should be a required method:

```
pub trait Xor {
    fn xor(&self, key_bytes: &[u8]) -> &[u8];
}

impl Xor for [u8] {
    fn xor(&self, key_bytes: &[u8]) -> &[u8] {
        for n in &self[..] {
            dbg!(n);
        }
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

Provided methods are usually for conveniences that only use other methods of the same trait, like most of the methods on `Iterator` (see [Why don't we implement all the functions from Iterator to implement an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40516692/why-dont-we-implement-all-the-functions-from-iterator-to-implement-an-iterator/40516724)).

> is it possible to implement the trait for several kind of types [without writing multiple `impl` blocks]?

Yes, if there is a trait that exposes the functionality you would use to write `Xor`, you may use that trait to write a generic `impl`. For example, `String` and `[u8]` both implement `AsRef<[u8]>`, so you can use that to write an `impl` that applies to both:

```
impl<T: ?Sized + AsRef<[u8]>> Xor for T {
    fn xor(&self, key_bytes: &[u8]) -> &[u8] {
        for n in &self.as_ref()[..] {
            dbg!(n);
        }
        unimplemented!()
    }
}
```

[Playground link.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=bfd417e8659dd6bb46160c210d3ad448)

### See also

- [How does Rust know which trait methods are required or provided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44642662/how-does-rust-know-which-trait-methods-are-required-or-provided) for more on provided and required trait functions
- [What does the question mark mean in a type parameter bound?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30333607/what-does-the-question-mark-mean-in-a-type-parameter-bound) for what `?Sized` means